# Recyclerview not updating on searchview text change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, searchview, notifydatasetchanged

Friends , I have an edittext which is acting like a searchview.On text change,it is fetching data and storing in filterdNames but it is not updating the recyclerview.Kindly help, i am new to andriod.
Here is my recyclerview adapter code-

```
public class MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox.ViewHolder> {
    List<GetMyCategoryAdapter> getMyCategoryAdapter;
    Context context;
    List<String> category_name;
   GetMyCategoryAdapter getMyCategoryAdapter1;

    public MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox(List<GetMyCategoryAdapter> getMyCategoryAdapter, Context context, List<String> category_name) {
    this.getMyCategoryAdapter = getMyCategoryAdapter;
    this.context = context;
    this.category_name = category_name;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof ViewHolder){
        }
        getMyCategoryAdapter1 =  getMyCategoryAdapter.get(i);
      ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).tv_categorytitle.setText(getMyCategoryAdapter1.getC_name());
        ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).tv_categoryid.setText(getMyCategoryAdapter1.getC_id());
        ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).gt= getMyCategoryAdapter1;
    }

    public void filterList(ArrayList<String> filterdNames) {
       this.category_name = filterdNames;
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    } 
}
```

Here is my GetMyCategoryAdapter class code -

```
public class GetMyCategoryAdapter {
    String c_name,c_id;

    public String getC_name() {
        return c_name;
    }

    public void setC_name(String c_name) {
        this.c_name = c_name;
    }

    public String getC_id() {
        return c_id;
    }

    public void setC_id(String c_id) {
        this.c_id = c_id;
    }
}
```

And here is the fragment code -

```
searchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                //after the change calling the method and passing the search input
                filter(editable.toString());
            }
        });
   private void filter(String text) {
        //new array list that will hold the filtered data
        ArrayList<String> filterdNames = new ArrayList<>();

        //looping through existing elements
        for (String s : category_name) {
            //if the existing elements contains the search input
            if (s.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                //adding the element to filtered list
                filterdNames.add(s);
            }
        }

        //calling a method of the adapter class and passing the filtered list
        ((MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox) MyAdapter).filterList(filterdNames);



    }
```

Comment: in your filterlist method you notifyDataSetChanged(); adapter but it not work. remove this and set again adapter.

Comment: Post `onCreateViewHolder` and `getItemCount` methods of the adapter, please

Comment: @HemantParmar how should i do that?

Comment: @S-Sh..those methods have nothing to do with this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `filterList` method:
you update `category_name`, but not `getMyCategoryAdapter` (which is used in `onBindViewHolder`). Try change `getMyCategoryAdapter` as well before `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: i tried that but its not getting changed..can u tell me how should i change that ?